# How to send invitation to facebook friend from my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am working on Rails application. My application is currently in 'invitation only' mode. What I want to do is once user signed up to my application then user should be able to invite his Facebook friends to my application. So what is the best way to do it? I want to do similar like pinterest does. pinterest is also in invitation only mode. But still it allows my facebook friend to whom I have sent an invite to sign up directly. So how I can implement it in my application? Any guidance will be helpful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the requests dialog: 
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
2. Store the list of user id's you get back (which you need to do anyhow
   to delete the request programmatically when the come to your app)
3. When a user tries to login to your app, ensure that they're on your
   list of id's you stored earlier.
4. Delete their app request

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs

> **Deleting Requests**  When a user is directed to your application, by
>   clicking a Request from the application, the games dashboard, or from
>   a Request notification, you must delete the request after it has been
>   accepted. Requests are not automatically deleted once they have been
>   clicked, thus it is the developer’s responsibility to clear them once
>   they have been consumed.